# Android: Automated GUI Testing

Tags: android, user-interface, automated-tests

I would like to create some automated GUI tests for my android application.  I am aware of Robotium and other similar projects but I would like to create my own testing framework from scratch.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: your display name doesn't fit in the box, fyi lol

Comment: Robotium is open source, so why don't take a look at their source code for some inspiration?

Comment: @AlexLockwood: `TooLongNameException` lolx

Comment: @AdilSoomro, hahahah I'll have to remember that one for next time :D

Comment: "When you sort all of Stackoverflow's members alphabetically, I am last.": How creative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin by reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) on testing and then taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jayway/robotium) for Robotium. That's how I would get started, at least.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize Robotium was open source.  Thanks for the answer and I really like your blog.